# Encrypt in ORACLE and then Decrypt in C# .NET

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, encryption, cryptography

Here is my PL/SQL code for encryption:

```
declare
passphrase RAW(128) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('SECRET_KEY1111111');
plaintext RAW(128) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('5421123500005002');
cyphertext RAW(1024);
encdata  RAW (2000);
begin
cyphertext := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DES3Encrypt(input => plaintext, 
key => passphrase);
dbms_output.put_line('Encrypted:' || cyphertext);

encdata:=dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Decrypt(input=>hextoraw(cyphertext),key=>passphrase);

    dbms_output.put_line('Decrypted:' || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(HEXTORAW(encdata)));

end;
```

And my C# code for decryption:

```
        byte[] b = HexStringToByteArray("E98C498A316CBE3B6AE16A82A4BE2F0F");

        TripleDES des = TripleDES.Create();
        des.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SECRET_KEY1111111");
        //des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 

        des.IV = HexStringToByteArray("0123456789ABCDEF");
        ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] output = ct.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);//***EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE***

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output));
        Console.ReadLine();


        public byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string Hex)
        {
            byte[] Bytes = new byte[Hex.Length / 2];
            int[] HexValue = new int[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
       0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

            for (int x = 0, i = 0; i < Hex.Length; i += 2, x += 1)
            {
                Bytes[x] = (byte)(HexValue[Char.ToUpper(Hex[i + 0]) - '0'] << 4 |
                              HexValue[Char.ToUpper(Hex[i + 1]) - '0']);
            }

            return Bytes;
        }
```

PL/SQL result is here:

```
14:18:33  PL/SQL block executed
Encrypted:E98C498A316CBE3B6AE16A82A4BE2F0F
Decrypted:5421123500005002
14:18:33  **** SCRIPT ENDED 17.07.2017 14:18:33 ****
14:18:33  End Script Execution
```

In .NET side I am always getting an Exception.
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Bad Data.**

DBMS_CRYPTO is not allowed so I need to use DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT. I do not know what is the default properties of DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DES3Encrypt procedure.  For IV property should I use "0123456789ABCDEF" or "C992C3154997E0FB"? What should I do? Where is my problem? Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: At what point in your code does the exception occur? Does the oracle documentation say anything about the mode of operation that the *DES3Decrypt* function does use?

Comment: I don't see you using the intitialization vector in your SQL. The initialization vector should be randomly generated when encrypting,otherwise it doesn't add security. Then you should use the same initialization vector when decrypting, which means you have to store it with your encrypted data. Also, you use UTF-8 encoding for the key when decrypting, but not when you encrypt. This means you probably have a different key when you decrypt.

Comment: @mat I have edited my answer.

Comment: @PeterBruins I didnt set IV because I wanted to use the default one but I am not sure which one is. I think "0123456789ABCDEF"